# Suppress logging in Azure Webjobs ("Executing: 'xxx' because New queue message detected on 'yyy'.")

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is there a way to suppress log entries of `Executing: 'xxx' because New queue message detected on 'yyy'.`?
I still want to see my logs (written to Console), however I'm not interested in seeing `Executing (...)` entries. Those do not provide me any value and those are the majority of the logs now.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the Console log level globally via `JobHostConfiguration.Tracing.ConsoleLevel`. Those "Executing/Executed" messages are traced at the `TraceLevel.Info` level which is the default. You can set the log level to `TraceLevel.Warning` or `TraceLevel.Error` and you won't see them anymore (you'll see only warnings/errors).

However, that setting will also apply to any logs that you write from your job functions via a `TextWriter` job parameter (if that's what you mean by "your logs"). If that isn't what you want, you could register your own custom `TraceWriter` via the `JobHostConfiguration.Tracing.Tracers` collection. If you then replaced your `TextWriter` parameters with `TraceWriter` parameters and used one of the trace overloads that allows you to specify a "source", your custom TraceWriter could allow your logs through. See the custom TraceWriter sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Program.cs).

For completeness, there is also an attribute that you can apply at the class or method level to control function logging. For example, if you apply `[TraceLevel(TraceLevel.Error)]` to a particular job method, you'll **only** get logs if that function fails. Note that this attribute will affect Dashboard logging as well as Console logging.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I need to register custom TraceWriter. Any chances making ConsoleTraceWriter public? I would avoid making one. Which seems to be simple, but existing ConsoleTraceWriter has some nice features (filtering by level, coloring, avoiding extra lines in log, logging additional details from exceptions).